# Android: TextView Above RecyclerView on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, textview

Okay, I need some help because this is driving me insane. I've gone through every post I could find on StackOverflow about this and I have tried EVERYTHING. The Preview, I should mention, looks perfect. But when I run the app the TextView simply isn't there.

I've followed the suggestion that said to make the RelativeLayout "focusable." I tried the one that said to put the TextView under the RecyclerView. I tried the one that goes something like "LayoutAbove=@recyclerviewid".

I have literally tried everything that I found on StackOverflow and nothing has worked and I can't understand why it would work in the preview but not in the app. I don't understand that at all.  Anyway! The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:text="EVENTS"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/events_view"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:** As per TakeInfo's answer... (and this is very important and I did not know it...) the ONLY reason the code above wasn't working was because I used "tools:text="EVENTS"" which meant that the "text" only gets sent to Android Studio.

I will of course leave this question up here because I'm sure I'm not the only one who didn't know that.

This question wasn't as simple as some people may have thought... it actually had nothing to do with the layout... but an error in the code. I think most people just dismissed the question at first glance without really LOOKING at what the problem might be. A lesson for us all. :)

Comment: Add a id to textview and add rule `android:layout_below="@+id/textView"` to `Recyclerview`.

Comment: Simply use _android:layout_above="@+id/events_view"_

Comment: @Piyush I think there was another error in my code that was preventing everything I tried from working. Maybe something to do with the "tools" in TextView. But I tried "layout_above" and it did absolutely nothing when I tried it. I'm sure it would work now that I've corrected whatever was wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android:text="EVENTS"` instead of `tools:text="EVENTS"`

when you use 'tools' it only displays text in the android studio.

Give an id to textview and align your recyclerview to below the textview.

```html
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="EVENTS"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/events_view"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your xml, switch places with your TextView and the RecyclerView.

The xml is "drawn" from top to bottom, so the TextView will be drawn before and then the recyclerView will be drawn above the TextView.

Switching them will make the TextView to be drawn after the recycler view.

Comment: One thing to be aware on your setup, is that the elements of the recyclerView will be visible behind the text after scrolling down, this because the recyclerView starts on the same "top" as the TextView, but has a padding that makes the First element to be shown bellow the textView. I would suggest to use android:layout_below and android:layout_above to adjust the position of your views

Comment: No that's actually the way I want it. I want Events to stay where it is and for the elements of the recyclerview to scroll under it. I just checked now and it looks fine. Good to know for the future though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Give TextView id attribute like this

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Then add this attribute in it

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
```

in the RecyclerView element

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just use LinearLayout with orientation vertical. So that all your views will appear one below another.

Comment: This must be a comment.

Comment: Bro I have not this much reputation to comment on answer.

Comment: As i know when you have 50 reputation you can comment.

Comment: Yes just received +8 after answering this question. Now on-words i will surely able to comment on answers. Thank you.